# iOS - SearchBar jumping to top as i tap on it to enter text

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    definesPresentationContext = true
    self.tableView?.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is default behavior when you add the search bar to tableview header.

Comment: even if I add on normal UIView for eg.    self.customView.addSubview(searchController.searchBar), then it's also showing the same behavior